# Save only the inside area of the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I would like to save only the inside are of the plot. The plot (the area I must save) has a fixed aspect ratio.

So, instead of saving [this](https://imgur.com/a/2QBYYEj), I must save only [this](https://imgur.com/a/rGE78Mt).

What's the simplest way to do it?

What I tried:

I can save the original file first and then crop it using PIL. That works, but if the size of the graph changes I must manually set all four values again by trial and error...

```
im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
```

Simply disabling the axes visualisation and saving the complete area of the figure isn't ideal for my specific application.

I also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676770/save-specific-part-of-matplotlib-figure), but my axes don't start and end exactly at a tick so I can not do it that way.

Comment: In this case, can't you write a simple script that uses `PIL` to read the image's pixel values and look for a shade of green? It should be simple as what you are trying to crop is a rectangle that has a different colour from the rest of the image.

Comment: It is not very clear to me why the solution you refer to is not applicable because of ticks consideration.

Comment: Also, I don't get the remark about aspect ratio. I don't think the example you provided illustrated those problems you refer to. Could you provide an example that illustrate that? And what are the expected output exactly (how it should be cropped)

Comment: Note that using PIL should be avoidable. It is just a matter of computing the bounding box. It is not very advisable to post-process the image, by a library that know nothing of the internal of how the image was generated (it would require to know exactly from which pixel to which pixel you should extract the subimage. And if you know that, it is probable that you should be able to compute the bbox in the first place)

Comment: Maybe plot the line in a colour very different from the axes/background and title and then use PIL to make all those other colours transparent, then crop.

Comment: `x0,x1 = 0.2, 0.6  y0,y1 = 0.4, 0.8` can be done as `x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()` and `y0,y1 = get_ylim()`, so _but my axes don't start and end exactly at a tick so I can not do it that way._ is irrelvant

Comment: Please remove Tkinter from the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you linked is relevant, but instead of starting with the specific data values you can start with `ax.get_position()`, which gives you the axes bounding box as figure fraction.  Then you can use the `fig.transFigure` transform to get from figure fraction to pixel space.  Then, like the previous answer use the inverted `dpi_scale_trans` transform to get from pixel space to inches.

I also here set the spines to invisible so you don't get a black line around the edge of the image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor("palegreen")
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.plot(range(5), "o-")
ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)

bbox = ax.get_position().transformed(fig.transFigure).transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())

fig.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches=bbox)
```

[image]